# How to customize X-axis category in SGPLOT?

Tags: sas

The SGPLOT code I wrote is as follows

```
proc sgplot data=via05;

xaxis label = " ";
yaxis label = " ";

styleattrs
dataconstrastcolors = (black red blue skyblue orange green grig);

series x=rq_pt y=count_time / datalabel
group=gro lineattrs=(thickness=3)
grouplp=grouplinepattern;
run;
```

In the via05 dataset, the number of rq_pt values ​​is 72 in total.
However, as these 72 are displayed on the x-axis as they are, I found a problem that the graph is too messy.

**So what I want to implement is On the x-axis, I want only certain indicators to be displayed.**

If you have any code that can be implemented, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some sample data or messy image?

In this generated data the X-axis does not display tics for every `x`.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(2023);
  do group = 'A', 'B', 'C';
    grouplinepattern = (rank(group) - 64) * 3;
    do x = 1 to 72;
      y = rand('integer', 20,250);
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

ods listing;

proc sgplot data=have;

  xaxis label = " ";
  yaxis label = " ";

  styleattrs
    datacontrastcolors = (black red blue skyblue orange green ligr)
  ;

  series 
    x = x
    y = y
  /
    group = group
    grouplp = grouplinepattern
    datalabel
    lineattrs=(thickness=3)
  ;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: It is not possible to attach an image by adding a comment, so I suggested an additional opinion myself, so please check it.